# Map resources when added to the project bundle

Tags: iphone, xcode, scripting

I have a .h when I map all the image files names and xib names with #defines. For example, if I have an image called "buttonBackground.png" I map it in my .h as

```
#define BUTTON_BACKGROUND_PNG_FILE   @"buttonBackground.png"
```

It's possible to detect when a resource is added to the bundle and create the correspond define with a script?

EDIT: I mean, something like `R.java` file on Android.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could accomplish this by adding a Run Script build phase to your target, after Copy Bundle Resources. The script would look inside the bundle (which has just been freshly created by the rest of the build process) and generate your header file based on the resources it finds there.

You'd want to avoid regenerating the header when there aren't any new resources, because that would slow down your builds (since every .m file that depends on that header will be recompiled whenever the header is touched). A quick approximation: have your script start by comparing the modification time of the project.pbxproj file with that of the header, and exiting if the header is newer. A better (but somewhat more complicated) way: generate a scratch file, diff it with the current header, and replace the header with the scratch file if and only if they differ.

But honestly, this seems like a lot of work for not much benefit, not to mention that monolithic headers are a bad idea in general. Do your filenames change often enough that you need to refer to them indirectly? In other words, what problem are you trying to solve with all these #defines?

Comment: Thanks for the answer dwineman. What I want to accomplish is to avoid the complications due to the change of filenames and the inconsistency of the applications due to the large size of it. It's better, IMHO, the loss of 30 seconds mapping the resource into a file that, in case of a filename change (something very easy because the fragmentation of big projects), review entire project changing the name (or, using the search&replace, break something). Maybe it's a "bad" strategy but in terms of security I think is better than trust in the consistency of filenames.

Answer (score 0):

`xxd` is the command line tool to manage embedded resources, but specifically for images you can take a page from the web playbook and do base64 as well in your header files.  There is [an article on Cocoanetics about Embedded Binary Resources](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2010/10/embedding-binary-resources/) about these tactics.

You could also roll your own build scripting to automate this with Bash or Rake or something like that too of course like @dwineman is talking about, but all that diffing/scratch file stuff will probably just end up as a fragile build system riddled with bugs you don't have time to fix because you need to build the actual product.  Keep it simple with this one, don't over-engineer anything.  I like #defines just as much as the next guy, but everything in moderation.

Comment: Wow, that base64 stuff sure sounds like a bad idea. For starters, it defeats the imageNamed cache, which gets automatically flushed when your app enters the background on iOS 4.0. Since background apps get terminated roughly in order of memory use, this can be a huge concern.

Comment: I'm with you on that, glad you mentioned it.  Like I said, everything in moderation and keep this as simple as possible.